# mi iframe no funciona con variables en php

Tags: php, html, iframe

tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo varias graficas divididas y las estoy insertando una a una en una ventana nueva por medio de iframe el problema es que esa ventana ya viene con variables definidas que traen datos para poder generar las gráficas:

La grafica 1 como se ve en el ejemplo esta en el archivo flot190.php

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="flot190.php" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

El problema es que no lee las variables que ya tengo en el tablero.php que es la ventana principal, el iframe es como si estuviese aparte.

Como puedo hacer para que tome las variables que ya vienen en mi php para que se genere la gráfica correctamente?

Por otro lado si uso:

```
<?php
    include('flot190.php');
?>
```

```
<div id="kpi2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;margin-top:20px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(158,158,158,0.52);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(158,158,158,0.52);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(158,158,158,0.52);"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#kpi2').highcharts({
        colors: ['#f30707','#03deec','#6f13aa'],

        title: {
            text: 'ACUMULADO CONSUMO DE LLANTAS NUEVAS <br>FLOTA: <b><?php echo $flotad; ?></b>',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Período: 2019',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {

            categories: [


            <?php

$sql1=mysql_query("
select llanta_mont,km_llantam,hr_llantam,flota_mont,mes,mes_annio,fecha_mont,COUNT(*) as flot190 FROM montajes WHERE flota_mont='$flotad' and km_llantam='0' 
and hr_llantam='0' and fecha_mont BETWEEN '2019-01-01' and '$fecha_md1' GROUP BY mes ORDER BY mes_annio");
while($res1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){      

        $flot190=$res1['flot190'];
        $mes=$res1['mes'];
?>  


['<?php echo $mes; ?>' ],

<?php
}

  ?>

            ],crosshair: true
        }, 
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
      format: '{value}',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Cantidad de llantas',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    }
  }, { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: 'Acumulados',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} ',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },        

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Cantidad',
            color: '#96f4b9',
            data: [
                            <?php


$sql1=mysql_query("select llanta_mont,km_llantam,hr_llantam,flota_mont,mes_annio,mes,fecha_mont,COUNT(*) as flot190 FROM montajes WHERE flota_mont='$flotad' and km_llantam='0' 
and hr_llantam='0' and fecha_mont BETWEEN '2019-01-01' and '$fecha_md1' GROUP BY mes ORDER BY mes_annio");
while($res1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){      

        $flot190=$res1['flot190'];
?>  



            [<?php echo $flot190; ?>],

<?php


}
?>

            ]
        }, {
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Acumulado',
            color: '#024616',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [
                            <?php


$sql1=mysql_query("select llanta_mont,km_llantam,hr_llantam,flota_mont,mes_annio,mes,fecha_mont,COUNT(*) as flot190 FROM montajes WHERE flota_mont='$flotad' and km_llantam='0' 
and hr_llantam='0' and fecha_mont BETWEEN '2019-01-01' and '$fecha_md1' GROUP BY mes ORDER BY mes_annio");
$acumulado='0';
while($res1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){      

        $flot190=$res1['flot190'];
        $acumulado=$flot190+$acumulado;
?>  



            [<?php echo round($acumulado); ?>],

<?php


}
?>

            ]
        }, {
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Planeado',
            color: '#ef0808',
            yAxis: 1,
            dashStyle: 'Dash',
            data: [
                            <?php


$sql1=mysql_query("select id_plane,flota_plane,fecha_plane,mes_plane,cant_plane,COUNT(*) as flot190 FROM planeado WHERE flota_plane='$flotad' 
and fecha_plane BETWEEN '2019-01-01' and '$fecha_md1' GROUP BY mes_plane ORDER BY mes_plane");
$acumulado='0';
while($res1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){      

        $cant_plane=$res1['cant_plane'];

        $acumulado=$cant_plane+$acumulado;
?>  



            [<?php echo round($acumulado); ?>],

<?php


}
?>

            ]
        }]
    });
});
        </script>

<table>
<tr>
<th><font color="#ffffff">FILTROS:</font> 

<a href="?datos=<?php echo $fecha_md?>&datos1=<?php echo $fecha_md1?>&flotad=<?php echo $flotad='320'?>&periodo=<?php echo $fechaperido?>&periodorep=<?php echo $fechaperidorep?>&turno=<?php echo $turno_diario?>&fechaturno=<?php echo $fechatur?>" class="boton_personalizado">320</a>

<a href="?datos=<?php echo $fecha_md?>&datos1=<?php echo $fecha_md1?>&flotad=<?php echo $flotad='240'?>&periodo=<?php echo $fechaperido?>&periodorep=<?php echo $fechaperidorep?>&turno=<?php echo $turno_diario?>&fechaturno=<?php echo $fechatur?>" class="boton_personalizado">240</a>

<a href="?datos=<?php echo $fecha_md?>&datos1=<?php echo $fecha_md1?>&flotad=<?php echo $flotad='190'?>&periodo=<?php echo $fechaperido?>&periodorep=<?php echo $fechaperidorep?>&turno=<?php echo $turno_diario?>&fechaturno=<?php echo $fechatur?>" class="boton_personalizado">190</a>


<th><form action="../procesos/reportes/excell/total_llantasnuevas.php" method="GET">
<input type='hidden' name='datoss' value="<?php echo $_GET['datos']; ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='datoss1' value="<?php echo $_GET['datos1']; ?>">

<input type="submit" class="boton_personalizado" id="consul" value="Excel">
</form></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

De esa forma si funciona la gráfica, pero necesito que funcione con el iframe.

Quedo atento a cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar, muchas gracias.

Comment: comparte lo que tienes en flot190.php

Comment: Listo alli acabo de poner lo que esta dentro del archivo flot190.php